# Why does "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" cause 'Update application manifest' save to fail with 'credential limit reached'?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've set up an app in Azure Active Directory and I want to allow personal accounts access to the app. The only change I make is to switch "signin Audience" from "AzureADMultipleOrgs" to the label in the title and I've suddenly reached my credential limit. Is this referring to user credentials? It's not clear... Any advice appreciated.

[error message in manifest json editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm4ZQ.jpg)
i'm using a free trial subscription to azure as part of office 365

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: link added. "Failed to update XXX application. Error detail: Unable to save changes because the credential limit has been reached. Please delete a credential and try again. [gU2X0]"

Comment: Did you change anything else in the manifest?

Comment: No other changes made. Question edited to reflect, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Applications which support personal Microsoft accounts as sign in audience (i.e. `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`) must have no more than two key credentials and no more than two password credentials.

Before changing the sign in audience, you need to remove additional credentials until you have (at most) two of each kind. In the Azure portal, you can manage credentials for your app registration under "Certificates and secrets". Using the manifest (or Azure AD PowerShell or Graph API), you would modify the `keyCredentials` and `passwordCredentials` properties to remove extra credentials.

Comment: That is a magical set of requirements that now bites me scripting B2C apps vs AAD apps - can you share where this is documented?

Comment: @felickz we recently hit this as well and eventually found this requirement here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/supported-accounts-validation

Comment: Changing it to `AzureADMyOrg` solved it for me

Comment: Also this solves the issue for the error that states "Unable to save changes because the credential limit has been reached. Please delete a credential and try again" which is slightly different from OP's question but the solution is the same.